# Ubuntu 20.04 (kernel 5.4.0-80-generic) - Unstable (and slow) wifi

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, iwlwifi

My wireless device is an Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275. Although my bluetooth is working fine, it looks like whenever I'm using a bluetooth device the internet connection is even worse. I'm using an ASUS laptop, the drivers and BIOS were updated recently (less than a year ago).

In the last few days, my internet connection has been painfully slow and unstable. At first, I thought it was a problem with the provider, however, when using Windows on another computer the internet is working perfectly fine. I could not find any solution for this problem and I do have reasons to believe I'm not the only one experiencing this issue.

Some "diagnostics" below:

```
> modinfo iwlwifi


filename: /lib/modules/5.4.0-80-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license: GPL
author: Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description: Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware: iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-50.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-50.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-50.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-so-a0-jf-b0-50.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-cc-a0-50.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-QuQnj-b0-jf-b0-50.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-50.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-50.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-50.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-50.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-QuQnj-a0-hr-a0-50.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-QuQnj-b0-hr-b0-50.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-QuQnj-f0-hr-a0-50.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-Qu-a0-jf-b0-50.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-Qu-a0-hr-a0-50.ucode
srcversion: E8E9F5689D56ED765B15F2A
alias: pci:v00008086d00007AF0sv*sd00000A10bc*sc*i*

...
alias: pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001201bc*sc*i*
depends: cfg80211
retpoline: Y
intree: Y
name: iwlwifi
vermagic: 5.4.0-80-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
sig_id: PKCS#7
signer: Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key: **********
sig_hashalgo: sha512
signature: ***
parm: swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm: 11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm: amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 2K for AX210 devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K 4: 2K (default 0) (int)
parm: fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm: antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm: nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm: lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm: uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm: enable_ini:Enable debug INI TLV FW debug infrastructure (default: 0 (bool)
parm: bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm: led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm: power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm: power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm: fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)
parm: disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm: remove_when_gone:Remove dev from PCIe bus if it is deemed inaccessible (default: false) (bool)
parm: disable_11ax:Disable HE capabilities (default: false) (bool)


> lsmod | grep iwlwifi 

iwlwifi 331776 1 iwlmvm
cfg80211 704512 3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211

> dmesg | grep iwlwifi

[ 3.930373] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[ 3.930384] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[ 3.931189] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.77d01142.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[ 4.078576] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8265, REV=0x230
[ 4.088197] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[ 4.089360] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[ 4.148219] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: a0:af:bd:c1:a8:fe
[ 4.590164] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[ 7.408915] Modules linked in: cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_seq kvm_intel iwlmvm joydev snd_seq_device kvm nouveau(+) crct10dif_pclmul mac80211 snd_timer libarc4 ghash_clmulni_intel snd aesni_intel btusb iwlwifi uvcvideo crypto_simd btrtl asus_nb_wmi btbcm cryptd asus_wmi input_leds btintel glue_helper videobuf2_vmalloc rapl i915 sparse_keymap serio_raw wmi_bmof videobuf2_memops mxm_wmi bluetooth soundcore intel_cstate videobuf2_v4l2 ttm cfg80211 videobuf2_common ecdh_generic mei_me ecc hid_multitouch drm_kms_helper intel_xhci_usb_role_switch mei i2c_algo_bit intel_pch_thermal roles processor_thermal_device fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt intel_rapl_common intel_soc_dts_iosf int3403_thermal
[ 7.757524] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[ 7.898881] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[ 7.967326] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[ 36.112247] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_seq kvm_intel iwlmvm joydev snd_seq_device kvm nouveau crct10dif_pclmul mac80211 snd_timer libarc4 ghash_clmulni_intel snd aesni_intel btusb iwlwifi uvcvideo crypto_simd btrtl asus_nb_wmi btbcm cryptd asus_wmi input_leds btintel glue_helper videobuf2_vmalloc rapl i915 sparse_keymap serio_raw wmi_bmof videobuf2_memops mxm_wmi bluetooth soundcore intel_cstate videobuf2_v4l2 ttm cfg80211 videobuf2_common ecdh_generic mei_me ecc hid_multitouch drm_kms_helper intel_xhci_usb_role_switch mei i2c_algo_bit intel_pch_thermal roles processor_thermal_device fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt intel_rapl_common intel_soc_dts_iosf
[ 46.218120] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_seq kvm_intel iwlmvm joydev snd_seq_device kvm nouveau crct10dif_pclmul mac80211 snd_timer libarc4 ghash_clmulni_intel snd aesni_intel btusb iwlwifi uvcvideo crypto_simd btrtl asus_nb_wmi btbcm cryptd asus_wmi input_leds btintel glue_helper videobuf2_vmalloc rapl i915 sparse_keymap serio_raw wmi_bmof videobuf2_memops mxm_wmi bluetooth soundcore intel_cstate videobuf2_v4l2 ttm cfg80211 videobuf2_common ecdh_generic mei_me ecc hid_multitouch drm_kms_helper intel_xhci_usb_role_switch mei i2c_algo_bit intel_pch_thermal roles processor_thermal_device fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt intel_rapl_common intel_soc_dts_iosf
[ 4470.012853] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[ 4470.148543] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[ 4470.218212] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[ 5212.966489] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_seq kvm_intel iwlmvm joydev snd_seq_device kvm nouveau crct10dif_pclmul mac80211 snd_timer libarc4 ghash_clmulni_intel snd aesni_intel btusb iwlwifi uvcvideo crypto_simd btrtl asus_nb_wmi btbcm cryptd asus_wmi input_leds btintel glue_helper videobuf2_vmalloc rapl i915 sparse_keymap serio_raw wmi_bmof videobuf2_memops mxm_wmi bluetooth soundcore intel_cstate videobuf2_v4l2 ttm cfg80211 videobuf2_common ecdh_generic mei_me ecc hid_multitouch drm_kms_helper intel_xhci_usb_role_switch mei i2c_algo_bit intel_pch_thermal roles processor_thermal_device fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt intel_rapl_common intel_soc_dts_iosf


> dmesg | grep "no suitable firmware found!"

> lspci -k | grep -A3 82[67]5
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

> iwconfig wlp2s0
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"REGINA"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 14:D6:4D:B7:ED:B4   
          Bit Rate=28.9 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=40/70  Signal level=-70 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:1  Invalid misc:28   Missed beacon:0
```

I have already tried disabling 802.11n, disabling IPv6 support, and also the power save options. Nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Your last command uses wrong quotes, retry with `dmesg | grep "no suitable firmware found!"` .

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I ran the command with the appropriate quotes, it was a "copy and paste" error.

Comment: Ok, no problem. Output of `lspci -k | grep -A3 82[67]5` maybe useful too.

Comment: Have you tried to reboot with previous kernel version?

Comment: Yes! I have tried to install more updated kernels from [here](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) as well. It had no effect though

Comment: Have you tried to move laptop closer to Wi-Fi access point? Or maybe change active channel on it? What is the AP/router model? What do you have for `iwconfig wlp2s0` output?

Comment: Yes, I have. I just included the `iwconfig` output to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127928/discussion-between-n0rbert-and-lcgodoy).